# geom_text shows several values

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm trying to create a barplot where I filter by medals. I want my graph to show the total sum of medals as text. I have joined two data sets and by that I have the total number of medals shown 3 times for each country. I want my graph to only show the total sum once.

**Code**:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

c %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = factor(reorder(region, medals)), y = medals, fill = Medal)) +
 geom_col() +
 coord_flip() +
 geom_text(aes(label = med_count), vjust=1, colour="black",
           position=position_dodge(.9), size=3)
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Data**:

```
> dput(c)
structure(list(region = structure(c(
  34L, 34L, 34L, 153L, 153L, 153L, 68L, 68L, 68L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 
  63L, 63L, 63L, 136L, 136L, 136L, 178L, 178L, 178L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
  179L, 179L, 179L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 49L, 49L, 49L, 64L, 64L, 64L, 130L, 
  130L, 130L, 171L, 171L, 171L, 40L, 40L, 40L), 
  .Label = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", 
             "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua", "Argentina", "Armenia",
             "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", 
             "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
             "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", 
             "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei",
             "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cambodia",
             "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands", 
             "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China", 
             "Colombia", "Comoros", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", 
             "Croatia", "Cuba", "Curacao", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
             "Democratic Republic of the Congo", "Denmark", "Djibouti", 
             "Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", 
             "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia",
             "Ethiopia", "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "Gabon", "Gambia",
             "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Grenada", "Guam",
             "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti",
             "Honduras", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", 
             "Individual Olympic Athletes", "Indonesia", "Iran", "Iraq",
             "Ireland", "Israel", "Italy", "Ivory Coast", "Jamaica", 
             "Japan", "Jordan", "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", 
             "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Laos", "Latvia", 
             "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein",
             "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macedonia", "Madagascar",
             "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", 
             "Marshall Islands", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", 
             "Micronesia", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro",
             "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru",
             "Nepal", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger",
             "Nigeria", "North Korea", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", 
             "Palau", "Palestine", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", 
             "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", 
             "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Refugee Olympic Team", 
             "Republic of Congo", "Romania", "Russia", "Rwanda", 
             "Saint Kitts", "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent", "Samoa",
             "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", 
             "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", 
             "Slovakia", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia",
             "South Africa", "South Korea", "South Sudan", "Spain",
             "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden",
             "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania",
             "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad", 
             "Tunisia", "Turkey", "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda",
             "UK", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", "Uruguay", "USA", 
             "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela", "Vietnam", 
             "Virgin Islands, British", "Virgin Islands, US", "Yemen", 
             "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), 
  med_count = c(447, 447, 447, 385, 385, 385, 373, 373, 373, 371, 
                371, 371, 269, 269, 269, 244, 244, 244, 227, 227, 
                227, 176, 176, 176, 144, 144, 144, 143, 143, 143, 
                106, 106, 106, 102, 102, 102, 87, 87, 87, 86, 86, 
                86, 80, 80, 80), 
  Medal = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
                      1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
                      1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
                      1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L), 
                    .Label = c("Bronze", "Gold", "None", "Silver"), 
                    class = "factor"), 
  medals = c(58L, 230L, 159L, 103L, 169L, 113L, 81L, 147L, 145L, 109L, 
             80L, 182L, 167L, 24L, 78L, 68L, 89L, 87L, 81L, 85L, 61L, 
             70L, 51L, 55L, 66L, 40L, 38L, 65L, 39L, 39L, 66L, 27L, 13L,
             55L, 22L, 25L, 32L, 32L, 23L, 10L, 50L, 26L, 34L, 16L, 30L)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -45L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: May you share your data by `dput(olympics)`

Comment: @Clueless Link to external data source does **not** count as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In addition, if your question is concerned with plotting, others should not be expected to re-trace every step you took to process your data to get to that point. You'll probably get quicker help if you include `dput(c)` in your question, rather than wait for others to download the dataset, filter, & create intermediate data objects `a` / `b` before they even have sight of your actual problem.

Comment: added dput(c) now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for:

```
c %>%

  # process the variable values before passing the data frame to ggplot(),
  mutate(Medal = forcats::fct_relevel(Medal, "Gold", "Silver", "Bronze", "None"),
         region = forcats::fct_reorder(region, med_count)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = region, y = medals, fill = Medal)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(y = med_count,      # position the label based on total medals per region
                label = med_count),
            hjust = 0,              # left-align labels to total medal count 
                                    # (default is central alignment)
            nudge_y = 5,            # offset labels slightly to the right
            check_overlap = TRUE,   # for three labels overlapping in the same position, 
                                    # only plot the first one
            size=3) +

  # optional: a color palette that sort of rsembles the medal colours
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "BrBG") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you so much!